# Ansible create EC2 instances with subsequent numbers in the name in different subnets

Tags: loops, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ansible

I am able to create ec2 instances with subsequent numbers in the same subnet.

However, I have 2 internal subnets and I am trying to create web3 and web5 in internal_subnet_ids[0] and web4 in internal_subnet_ids[1]. How do I do this?

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    region: us-east-1
    state: present
    aws_ec2_specs:
      - image: "{{ ami_id }}"
        key_name: "{{ default_key_name }}"
        server_category: web
        vpc_subnet_id: "{{ internal_subnet_ids[0] }}"
        instance_type: t2.small
        server_numbers:
          - '3'
          - '4'
          - '5'
        exact_count: 1

  tasks:
    - name: Create EC2 Instances
      ec2:
        count: "{{ item.0.count | default(omit) }}"
        count_tag:
          Name: "{{ item.0.server_category + item.1 }}"
        exact_count: "{{ item.0.exact_count | default(omit) }}"
        image: "{{ item.0.image | mandatory }}"
        instance_tags: "{{ {'Name': item.0.server_category + item.1 }|combine(item.0.instance_tags) }}"
        instance_type: "{{ item.0.instance_type | mandatory }}"
        key_name: "{{ item.0.key_name | mandatory }}"
        region: "{{ region | mandatory }}"
        vpc_subnet_id: "{{ item.0.vpc_subnet_id | default(omit) }}"
        state: "{{ item.0.state | default(omit) }}"
      with_subelements:
        - "{{ aws_ec2_specs }}"
        - server_numbers
      when: state == "present"
      register: ec2lauched
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a solution, not the very 'pretty' but it would do for now.

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    region: us-east-1
    state: present
    aws_ec2_specs:
      - image: "{{ ami_id }}"
        key_name: "{{ default_key_name }}"
        server_category: web
        instance_type: t2.small
        server_numbers_subnet:
          - server_numbers: '3'
            vpc_subnet_id: "{{ internal_subnet_ids[0] }}"
          - server_numbers: '4'
            vpc_subnet_id: "{{ internal_subnet_ids[1] }}"
          - server_numbers: '5'
            vpc_subnet_id: "{{ internal_subnet_ids[0] }}"
        exact_count: 1

  tasks:
    - name: Create EC2 Instances
      ec2:
        count: "{{ item.0.count | default(omit) }}"
        count_tag:
          Name: "{{ item.0.server_category + item.1.server_numbers }}"
        exact_count: "{{ item.0.exact_count | default(omit) }}"
        image: "{{ item.0.image | mandatory }}"
        instance_tags: "{{ {'Name': item.0.server_category + item.1.server_numbers }|combine(item.0.instance_tags) }}"
        instance_type: "{{ item.0.instance_type | mandatory }}"
        key_name: "{{ item.0.key_name | mandatory }}"
        region: "{{ region | mandatory }}"
        vpc_subnet_id: "{{ item.1.vpc_subnet_id | default(omit) }}"
        state: "{{ item.0.state | default(omit) }}"
      with_subelements:
        - "{{ aws_ec2_specs }}"
        - server_numbers_subnet
      when: state == "present"
      register: ec2lauched
```